# Why am I getting a Data Type Mismatch when comparing a date in Microsoft Access even though I am using the # delimiter?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office

I have a table of people's names who have attended a class and the timestamp of when they attended that class.  This is stored in *Access*.  I am trying to get the names of people who attended class on a given day.  The code I wrote is as follows:

```
SELECT [Person Name], DateValue([Activity Start Date]) FROM [2019 Learning]
WHERE DateValue([Activity Start Date]) = #11/14/2019#
```

Even though the date I am looking for is contained in the table, when I run the query it works for a second and then I get an error message saying

> "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

It then changes all the data returned into "`#Name?`".  Can someone please help explain why I am getting this error?

Comment: Just to confirm: [Activity Start Date] is of a timestamp datatype in the table?  To me it seems like it's a string data type with an invalid date in it.  When the system tries to extract the date value it's failing due to a bad date format.

Comment: Yes but a database can't cast #13/1/2019# to a valid date since there aren't 13 months.  So one or more of the strings isn't a valid date; which is what is causing the data type mismatch.  You maybe able to use `isdate()` and an `iif` to check to see if the strings a valid date before trying to get the `datevalue()` from it.

Comment: [Activity Start Date] I believe is a String.  It looks as follows:  "11/14/2019 13:00 t"   How would I get the "11/14/2019" portion out of that and be able to use conditionals and compare it?

Comment: Look at the table; look at the design of the table; and look at the field activity start date and determine what datatype it is.  Without this we don't have enough info to proceed as we'd be making assumptions.

Comment: Another option is to write a query `SELECT * FROM [2019 Learning] where isdate([Activity Start date]= False`.  THis would identify the bad data that needs to be cleaned up before you're query would work.But again this assumes activity start date is not a date datatype.  If it is not being stored as date datatype, bad dates can get into the system; and when you try to use date functions on bad dates, you get the error your seeing

Comment: Access says it is a Date/Time data type.  I can change the format to show Short Date which shows me the 11/14/2019 portion of it.  But I still get the error when trying to query for a specific date.

Comment: Then i'm at a loss.  The logic looks sound and a date/time data type can't allow bad dates so it is odd behavior indeed.  Are any of the values null?

Comment: I used the isdate([Activity Start Date]) = False and got back rows that don't have any information entered.

Comment: so add `and [Activity Start Date] is not null` to the where clause and see if it runs.  If it does we have to ask how do you want to handle those entries that don't have dates?  Include or exclude them?  So then the result is `null = #11/14/2019#` Null can't be compared using equal thus an error.

Comment: SELECT * FROM [2019 Learning]
WHERE [Activity Start Date] is null    this returned rows where there was no date so as you pointed out, when it tries to compare #11/14/2019# to null it throws the error.

Comment: No.  `SELECT [Person Name], DateValue([Activity Start Date]) FROM [2019 Learning]
WHERE DateValue([Activity Start Date]) = #11/14/2019# and [Activity Start Date] is nut null`  and depending on order of operation in access maybe...`SELECT [Person Name], DateValue([Activity Start Date]) FROM (Select * from [2019 Learning] where [Activity Start Date] is nut null) A
WHERE DateValue([Activity Start Date]) = #11/14/2019#`

Comment: Ok, give me second to try your other suggestions

Comment: So lets back up for a second and ask: how do you want to handle the situations where [Activity Start Date] has no value (is null)?  Do you want to include these records in the results; or exclude them?

Comment: I want to exclude them.

Comment: Also, both the queries you suggested still resulted in the same error.

Comment: SELECT [Person Name], DateValue([Activity Start Date]) FROM [2019 Learning]
WHERE [Activity Start Date] is not null and DateValue([Activity Start Date]) = #11/14/2019#    This even threw the same error

Comment: @xQbert Access, unfortunately, can cast  #13/1/2019#  to a valid date just fine (try it). That's often a cause of confusion, since the date format changes to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateValue() function errors on null. Provide an alternate value. Can use Nz() function.

`DateValue(Nz([Activity Start Date], Date())) = #11/14/2019#`

Or use a date assumed would not be in the database, such as #12/31/2999#, instead of Date().

If you want to make double sure records with null are not captured, include additional filter criteria but still deal with Null in the equality. And with dynamic input like:

`DateValue(Nz([Activity Start Date], Date())) = [Forms]![MyForm]![MyControl] AND NOT [Activity Start Date] IS NULL`

Comment: Yes; but this now assumes that an alternative date should be used and that date is today.  and again while it works; it may not meet requirements.  This feels like a "House TV Series answer"  We'll cure them w/o really knowing the underlying cause and keep trying till we get it right.  Why not ask more questions to get to a quality answer?

Comment: Though full marks for indicating DateValue() function errors on null; this is the root cause of the error.

Comment: This is the only thing I have ran that didn't produce the error.  I think adding in the IN NOT NULL condition can help to ensure I don't receive false dates marked as today.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than substituting values in place of `Null` (which could potentially lead to undesired/confusing results, if such values are output by the query), another way to approach this might be to avoid the `datevalue` function altogether in the `where` clause.

Since datetimes in MS Access are merely numerical values for which the integer part of the number represents the date component and the decimal part represents the fraction of the day, or time component, you can use the following to obtain all records for `#11/14/2019#`:

```
select [Person Name], datevalue([Activity Start Date])
from [2019 Learning]
where [Activity Start Date] >= #11/14/2019# and [Activity Start Date] < #11/15/2019#
```

Here, `Null` values are automatically excluded as both comparison operators will return `Null` when supplied with `Null`, thereby excluding the record.

Comment: Oh Doh! However, will have to use `DateAdd("d",1,[Forms]![MyForm]![MyControl])` to calculate the end date with dynamic parameter.

Comment: Or have another textbox on form that calculates end date and reference that control in SQL criteria.